# When I first created the flutter project,its work...but

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-debugging

It worked normally when I first created the flutter project and debug the project as soon as I created it.
But after creating the second project, syntx errors continue to occur.

[I hate the red line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Q10.png)

Most error messages are like this

*Undefined class 'Key'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'Key'.*

*Undefined class 'Widget'.
Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'Widget'.*

*The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type '_MyHomePageState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'.*

I just created a project and debug the file..

Comment: Did you try clean and build?
flutter clean
may be dart analyzer stopped, close and reopen the vscode.
Create project in different directory

Comment: I uninstalled flutter and reinstalled it from scratch. I thought it was a vscode problem, but i think seems to be the path of the system environment variable

Comment: when you create a project folder, it should not have spaces in folder name, sometimes error occurred. after reinstalled does it works?

Comment: i think it is occured by VSC problem.
friday before, i create  new Flutter app and run debug mode.
it worked clean. but today, boot my notebook and run debug mode, same error and more error message appears.
So, i removed all flutter project, reinstall flutter. 
its works...
what the..

Answer (score 0):

Do `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`.If it doesn't work please delete and reinstall flutter sdk